# Setting up NodeJS to work on live server

Tags: node.js, server

I am using NodeJS on my window WAMP SERVER and I want to transfer my project to a live server, and also how do I setup NodeJS on my live server.

I would prefer a link on a tutorial or better still a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I too come across this. First I installed lamp in my server for this I referred this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu 
 go through each step-by-step.Next,Installing nodejs will takes three commands.
Ubuntu contains a version of Node.js in its default repositories that can be used to easily provide a consistent experience across multiple servers. The version in the repositories is 0.10.25. This will not be the latest version, but it should be quite stable.In order to get this version, use the apt package manager. We should refresh our local package index prior and then install from the repositories.

```
 sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

you'll also want to also install `npm`, which is the Node.js package manager. You can do this by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

This will allow you to easily install modules and packages to use with `Node.js`.

Answer (score -2):

To run Nodejs in Production mode you need to install these dependencies on the server

- 1) Nodejs (make sure it should be LTS version).
- 2) PM2 (Process manager to manage your NodeJS Project, It's will
  automatically start your app whenever your app will crash).
- 3) Nginx: as a web server to maintain the load balancing.

You need to follow this link to setup Nodejs Server for Production Mode
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04